# Where can I find the day in Pathfinder Kingmaker on PS4?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

I've searched a very long time and it is written in many forums that the day can be found on marking the hourglass but it doesn't work on PS4.

Unfortunately I need to know the day to meet Kresten on Moonday.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave an area, on the World Map it will tell you your last visit. It was suggested by some people online to "camp until moonday".